# Disable a Link in IR in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an Issue. I have three columns in my Interactive Report Table. First column is MID, its is hidden. The other columns are MNAME and Revenue. MID is the ID of MNAME. When ID is not null, certainly I am filling its MNAME. When ID is null then it is named in my query as 'Others'.

I have created a link for MNAME to other page in the Application. I would like to disable the link, when MID is null. Or in other Words, when MNAME is 'Others' then must be the Link disabled. How can I do this ?
Thank you so much in Advance for your Help and Comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apex itself, you can't as there's no "condition" for the "Link" property. Therefore, create a link yourself, within the Interactive Report's query.

For example:

```
select mid, 
       mname,
       revenue,
       --
       case when mid is null then null
            else '<a href="https://www.google.com">Click here</a>'
       end as link
from your_table
```

In `link` column's property palette, set **Escape special characters** to "No". Run the page; link should be visible only for rows where `MID` column's value isn't `NULL`.

---

If you're navigating to another page in your application,

```
then '<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:14:&SESSION.">Click here</a>'
```

---

If you want to pass values to another page:

```
then '<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:14:&SESSION.::NO::P14_MNAME,P14_MID:P1_MNAME,P1_MID">Click here</a>'
                                              --------- ------- ======== ======
                                              to P14 page       pass items from P1 page
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I would like to link this column with other page (Page:14) with Item P14_MID in the Application. How sholud I write your query after "else '<a href =..........." ? Can you please write this too. Thanks....

Comment: Application ID=111, Page=14, Item: P14_MID

Comment: I posted an example; have a look at the bottom of the answer. Substitute server and port with your values.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have made it. Actually I would like to see 'Others' too but without link. Here the cell is empty '-'. How can I do it ?

Comment: Use "others" instead of NULL, e.g. `case when mid is null then 'Others'`

Comment: I have done it. Link works good but this time apex doesn't transfer the other fields in form page. I should work on it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You can do that as well; have a look at another example I posted. It presumes that you're passing values from page P1 to page P14. Also, read documentation about **f?p**, it is all described in there.

Comment: Ok. I will do it. Thanks a lot.